# Create nuget package from a REST Web API Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nuget, nuget-package

I have a REST API web service in ASP.NET CORE 2.0 several projects (layers) in it. However, by larger forces, it can not be used as a service.

It was then suggested to create a nuget package for this WEB API. I've never created a nuget package and I've seen examples on the internet of simple projects being used as a nuget package and not a WEB REST API. The question is:

Can I generate a nuget package from my WEB API REST application?-

** **Edit**

--

**Larger Forces** => Fearful stackeholders

**Application Type** => Audit Log (for several other applications)

** Situation **

Applications will not be able to accomplish anything without logging in before, and stackeholders are concerned that this API will eventually stop working for some reason, and all applications that consume this service will stop working.

--

** Application Architecture **

- Controller
- Application
- Domain
- Repository
- etc ...

1) Do I need to change an Architecture?

2) If it is possible to use this API as a nuget package, do I use it as if it were a service? For example, I have a route => GET: http://localhost/api/logs. I would use these routes of the Controllers? Or would I access API resources in another way?

- Here is the repository for this project: https://github.com/LeoFelipe/AuditLog

Comment: You can turn any dll into a nuget package, but I can't wrap my head around turning an API into a nuget package.

Comment: Why would you want/need this? What are you going to do with such a package? Packages are for deploying bits of code into other projects, to provide ready-made functionality for the receiving project to use. It's hard to conceptualise how you would package an API project like that and what use it would be. And why can't it be used as a service? That's the whole point of an API, surely. Of course if you have some classes within the API solution which are re-usable and could be useful in other solutions then you could package _those_, but I doubt packaging the controllers has much value.

Comment: Skipping the use case rationale, [here's a (dated) post from Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx) that you can refer to. Hth.

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for the comment. I edited my question, which answers your questions.

Comment: What I have done in the past was: 1) publish and serve my own WebAPI. 2) Write a wrapper with an interface which my consumer used -- it was largely ignorant of the underlying REST API. 3) **Publish this wrapper as a NuGet package** which my consumer imported. Now if the REST API ever changed my consumer would have very little code to change. This also made developing the consuming code and test much easier since I could stub out the service interface.

Comment: "stackeholders are concerned that this API will eventually stop working for some reason". If it's something which is a dependency for lots of other systems, then it's not really much different to something like Active Directory, for example, and almost every business happily relies on that single point of failure. They just mitigate the risk with failover systems, high availability clusters etc. You can do the same, I would think.

Comment: " If it is possible to use this API as a nuget package, do I use it as if it were a service?" It is already a (web) service. Not sure what you're getting at here. Like I said before, what you could do is package up all the layers apart from "Controller" into a single package. Your other applications can then install the package, and call the application code directly as an internal part of their program, in order to do logging. (I mean instead of making a HTTP request to the API, which would then call the application code.)

Comment: So it becomes a component of each separate application, rather than a standalone application which other applications can make requests too. Assuming you still mandate that it connects to a single central database, then this still has a single point of failure for people to get worried about, but that's an issue for any application which relies on a database, and your DBAs and Ops engineers should have ways of mitigating that risk already.

Comment: Wait, [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), etc?

Answer (score -1):

The existing api can be converted into razor class library with controller support but all other configurations need to be done from the main application. The razor class library can be packed and referenced.

The Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.git) provides an endpoint which serves the static files from the embedded resource from the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI
Doesn't this work the way you want it to be? Isn't it a api which can be configured and used into other api? I think following this architecture should solve this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Swashbuckle is for generating Swagger out of your API code only. The question talks about a completely different problem.